# On the Theory of Infinite Step Processes of Sequential Decision Making

Tags: set-theory, game-theory, infinite-games

On the border of Set Theory and Game Theory there is a broad class of Infinite Step Processes of Sequential Decision Making that can be characterized by the main following property: a Future development of the process depends on the process Present state and does not depend directly on the process Past [1] (these processes have the same nature as for example chess and checkers have: a game Future depends on the game Present state and does not depend directly on the game Past).

Some examples of such Infinite Step Processes give us Differential Games in certain posing [2] and Infinite Stage Games of Search and Completion [3,4].

For these processes with the use of Axiom of Choice some generalizations of basic results, which are well known facts in case of Finite Step Decision Making Processes (for example, existence of a uniformly optimal strategy), can be proved [1,2].

But the question when information of process Past history additional to information of process Present state, for example, perfect information, does not improve and when such information does improve best guaranteed result in considered infinite stage processes (like chess, checkers, Games of Search and Completion) comparing with best guaranteed result provided by information of only process Present state has remained an open question.

For example, for chess and checkers (even without rules of stopping) information of game Past history additional to information of game Present state does not improve best guaranteed result but for Infinite Stage Games of Search and Completion, having just the same structure as chess and checkers [1], information of game Past history additional to information of game Present state does improve best guaranteed result [1,3].

So the question is: what criteria distinguish between processes for which information of process Past history in addition to information of process Present state does not improve best guaranteed result, and processes for which information of process Past history additional to information of process Present state does improve best guaranteed result?

References

1. B. I. Model’, The existences of an overall έ-optimal strategy and validity of Bellman’s
   functional equation in an extended class of dynamic processes. I; II, Engineering Cybernetics, No.5, 1975, pp. 13 – 19; No. 6, 1975, pp. 12 – 19.
2. B. I. Model’, A certain class of differential games, Engineering Cybernetics, No.2, 1978, pp. 32 – 38.
3. B. I. Model’, Games of search and completion, Journal of Mathematical Sciences, Vol. 80, No 2, 1996, pp. 1699 - 1744, Plenum Publishing Corporation, New York.
4. U. Abraham, R. Schipperus, Infinite games on finite sets, Israel Journal of Mathematics 159, 2007, pp. 205-219.

Comment: You are asking for literature dealing with the case of non-Markov processes?

Comment: First of all thank you for attention. But I don't ask for literature. I am speaking of an open question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I find this post somewhat unclear.

Comment: First of all I tried to atrect attension to a broad class of Infinite Step Processes of Sequential Decision Making that are scarsely investigated.

Comment: @BorisModel But this site isn't for attracting attention to topics, it's for specific, well-formed questions. Right now, this isn't one.

Comment: It looks as though this question will be closed soon. It is possible for a question to be reopened, but a *sine qua non* is that a precise question which can be plausibly answered by an expert be asked. (A question where key words are "important" and "not important" doesn't qualify.) Please see mathoverflow.net/help (in the menu above) for advice on formulating good questions for MathOverflow.

Comment: The difficulty to explain in short is that the subject of these Infinite Step Processes of Sequential Decision Making is scarcely investigated and so not so much known.

Comment: Are you asking about when stationary winning strategies exist? (See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864186900775 for a set-theoretic topology example, and http://ratio.huji.ac.il/dp/neyman/04.pdf for perhaps closer to your specific interest.)

Comment: My question is when strategies with, for example, perfect information does not improve best guaranteed result in infinite stage games (like chess, checkers, games of search and completion) comparing with best guaranteed result provided by strategies with information of only current position. In any case thank you very much for your attention. Really.

Comment: The question was edited to clarify it.

Comment: The edits are helping, but I still find the last paragraph which has the actual question difficult to parse. A possible edit might be: "So the question is: what criteria distinguish between processes for which information of process Past history in addition to information of process Present state does *not* improve best guaranteed result, and processes for which information of process Past history additional to information of process Present state *does* improve best guaranteed result?"  (The trouble is that I don't know the area and this suggestion might alter the technical meaning.)

Comment: You mention the case of chess, but in chess, the question of whether a given move is legal does sometimes depend on the past play, and not just on the current configuration, since for example one cannot castle after having moved the king (even if it subsequently moved back), and the three-fold repetition rule and the en passant rule clearly depend past play.

Comment: Perhaps one way to understand your topic is to consider determinacy questions, but using strategies that depend only on the prior move, rather than on the prior play history, as usual.  It is then easy to show that there are open games, and even clopen games, which do not admit this kind of strategy. For every game $G$, however, this is another game  $G'$, such that a player has a winning strategy in $G$ just in case he or she has a winning strategy in $G'$ that depends only on the previous move. Proof: replace the single moves in $G$ with moves consisting of the game history up to that point.

Comment: Strategies where players only have access to the previous $k$ moves (rather than the whole play) are called $k$-tactics. Marion Scheepers has several papers on this topic.

Comment: Concerning edditing: First of all thank you for your attention. To distinguish is much better, it was just I had meant, but my English (more precisely lack of English) did not permit me to find your editing, but with your permission I'll use it.

Comment: Concerning chess: I know that I was slightly incorrect, but I just didn't want to give to many details.and wanted to concentrate on main subject concerning possible influence of history on best guaranteed result. The idea of considering games G and G' is just beautiful. But I am not speaking of winning strategy or saddle point, I am speaking of infsup (or minmax) strategy and of best guaranted result which exist but can depend on information that is used.

Comment: I am aquainted with works of Prof. Scheepers, especially with his works concerning game of famous David Gale..I was lucky to find a similar game independently of David Gale and even earlier (see references [3] and [4]).

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins If you feel the question is by now clear enough (and reasonable for MO) to support a vote to reopen, then I'd be happy to do so as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like you will do so. And not only for me. I am already not so young, I am on retirement. But in course of 45 years (starting from being a student in Moscow State University, while lecturing 20 years in Ben-Gurion University (Israel) and now being on retirement in Toronto and trying at least not to forget what was done) I have always had a very strong feeling that these Infinite Stage Processes being on the border of Set Theory and Game Theory actually are not noticed no by those who are occupied in Set Theory nor by those who are occupied Game Theory.

Comment: So I always looked for possibilities to attract attension to them. And a question that was choosed among others and which seemed to me to be relatively easy to explain is one of those many efforts. But these question is interesting for me by itself also. I could not solve it in course of many years.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I voted to reopen, and I believe that the question would be well-answered by a concise summary discussion of stationary winning strategies and $k$-tactics, as mentioned by Noah and Andres in the comments.